# Use Facades within file contained within public folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a live project that I do not really want to touch, so I do not want to amend anything like the routes file.  What I need to do is create a type of test file that checks that the connection to the database is fine.

So within my public folder, I have created a plain PHP file.  I do not want to use php functions as I need to replicate what Laravel does.  What I am essentially trying to do is something like this

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName())
{
    print_r("Yes! successfully connected to the DB: " . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName());
} else {
    print_r("Cant connect");
}
```

Would it be possible to do this directly from the public folder in a standalone PHP file?

Thanks

Comment: Why not create a [console command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan)?

Comment: I am providing a URL to an application which checks this connection.  I cant give this application a console command, it needs to be a URL

Comment: In that case i'd make an API, you should check [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport)